# "Attract" or "Attracts"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

I'm working on an SAT grammar test and the sentence I'm struggling with is:

> This variety of tasks **attract** individuals with a broad range of experience.

The answer they marked correct is "attracts."

Then I was wondering would it be "attracts" or "attract?" When I search it up, some say attracts, because "attract" is the singular verb while "variety" is the singular subject. However, others say that "attract" is the correct one.

Comment: Singular: ***this variety attracts** them*. Plural: ***these varieties attract** them*.

Comment: In the UK, 'SAT' is/was an acronym, and thus 'a SAT ...' is required. I believe 'SAT' is an initialism in the US, hence 'as SAT'. // 'Search it up' is ungrammatical.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Ungrammatical, you're right. But there's a long tradition of adding 'up' to such verbs, eh? To look up a word. To think up an excuse. "To fright the animals and to kill them up".

Answer (score 1):

You don't give all the information supplied in the test. This might be of some help.

I don't consider 'variety' here to be classifiable as a *number-transparent quantificational noun*. Though arguably ambiguous, 'variety' here defaults to 'diversity' ... as in the following example:

> - *Manufacturers need large sales to justify offering a big variety in export markets.* [[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/variety)]

In contrast, with 'a variety of tasks were/was undertaken', '[a] variety [of]' **can** be seen as a *number-transparent quantificational noun* (a CGEL term; see [StoneyB's answer *here*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/342962/why-can-we-add-a-number-of-before-nouns/342994#342994)). This licenses 'A variety / large number / wealth of tasks **were** undertaken' (using notional agreement). Below is an example showing this usage:

> - *A variety of courses are offered to help students meet requirements.*  [[ACES;
>   GrammarGuide](http://grammarguide.copydesk.org/2006/02/20/collective-wisdom/)]

But I believe 'This variety of tasks attracts individuals with a broad range of experience', as a paraphrase of 'The large variety of tasks which is available attracts individuals with a broad range of experience' –  where singular *variety* (postmodified) requires *attracts* –  is intended.

Comment: It could just as easily mean "this particular variety of tasks" - as in "this variety of rose attracts honey bees." Does each individual have a broad range of experience, or do the applicants have diverse experience? It's kind of a crappy question, but if you apply a rule to it, you probably get the same answer regardless of how you interpret it.

Comment: ... variety of [tasks which *are* available] ... ??

Comment: Yes, it's a poor question. I've stated which possibility I believe to be the default reading, but OP doesn't give enough detail to be sure the question is at fault. But 'a variety of', like 'a wealth of', can be a compound quantifier taking plural agreement.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - As pointed out by @Hot Licks, my original answer was in error - I misread the question. I have changed the answer to make more sense.

---

Unfortunately this is a bone of contention that appears repeatedly on language forums. Some people (inexplicably and wrongly  in my opinion) insist that such a sentence requires a plural verb.

To me it is quite obvious that the sentence is basically as follows:

*This variety attracts individuals with a broad range of experience.*

which has an added clause, thus:

*This variety (of tasks) attracts individuals with a broad range of experience.*

**Answer**

In my opinion it is clearly and obviously singular. Therefore I agree with the answer provided by the examiners.

Comment: @Hot Licks  -  Oops! Thanks for catching that. Somewhere along the line I lost track. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: You also don't reference the number-transparent q-n possibility. 'A number of ' **always** takes plural agreement; 'a handful of', ' a percentage of', ... 'a wealth of' (+ noun count-usage) can do.